# I try to access a NFS mount via FTP. It works but the FTP Dir listing is very slow

Tags: ftp, nfs, debian-squeeze

I mount an NFS using this command:

`mount -o rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr serverip:/directory /mnt/directory`

However the mount appears on the client as expected a command like `ls -a` work pretty fast on the `nfs` mount. But when I try to list the mounted directory via FTP it gets very very slow 
( 1.250 bytes in 160,39s (0,01KB/s) ). But surprisingly downloading files via FTP from `nfs` work with normal speeds.

I tested several values for `rsize` and `wsize` parameter with no success.

Both client and server are running Debian squeeze and NFSv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I used glftpd as FTP Server and switched to vsftpd. Now everything works as expected.